# Php attachment from string

Tags: php, email, attachment, phpmailer, email-attachments

I have a script generating .pdf file. This script return this file as string and then I can save it with file_put_contents()

```
$output = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents("myfile.pdf", $output);
```

I want to add this file as attachment to my email using PHPMailer. If I have a file on disk I just write path to it and new name:

```
$mail->addAttachment('/path/to/file.pdf', 'newname.pdf');
```

But can I add attachment without saving myfile.pdf to disk? Something like that:

```
$mail->addAttachment($output, 'myfile.pdf');
```

This string returns an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function addAttachment() on a non-object
```

How can I transform string type to file type without saving?

UPD:
Full code

```
$output = $dompdf->output();
$name = 'title.pdf';
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.***.org';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = '***@***.orgg';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '******************';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

$mail->From = 'aaa@bbb.com';
$mail->FromName = 'John';
$mail->addAddress('peter@parker.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient

$mail->addStringAttachment($output, $name);

                          // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an [`addStringAttachment()`](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer-PHPMailer-PHPMailer.html#method_addStringAttachment) method that seems to fit your need:

> ### addStringAttachment()
>
> *Add a string or binary attachment (non-filesystem).*
>
> `public addStringAttachment(string $string, string $filename[, string $encoding = self::ENCODING_BASE64 ][, string $type = '' ][, string $disposition = 'attachment' ]) : bool`
>
> This method can be used to attach ascii or binary data, such as a BLOB record from a database.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just save the file to a temporary directory and then attach it from there? And add some code that once `PHPMailer->send()` returns TRUE that you delete the temporary file.

Look into the PHPMailer class and see what check it makes on the addAttachment method.

Also the error actually looks like your PHPMailer object is not initiated. Can you post your whole PHPMailer code block please.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple: just call `addStringAttachment` instead of `addAttachment`:

```
$mail->addStringAttachment($dompdf->output(), 'my.pdf');
```