# Sending e-mail via PHPMailer with attachments from URL

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer. I have to send two attachments and both are links (one is base64 image and the second one is url).

```
// Variables with images
$croped_img = 'data:image/jpg;base64,/extreme_long_code_here';
$photo_thumbnail_url = 'http://t2.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/76/44/75/400_F_76447580_gOWAV0P8APW0iC51OsW5huD6qoiEsh7O.jpg';

// PHPMailer
$mail->addAttachment('$photo_thumbnail_url', 'selected.jpg');
$mail->addAttachment('$croped_img', 'croped_img.jpg');
```

PHPMailer works because if I send e-mail in that form, attachments do not come. 
But if I link local image e.g. `'images/abc.jpg'` then they comes.

What php functions should I use to send my variables as e-mail attachments?

Comment: You sould use the method AddEmbeddedImage

Comment: But how to use this in my case? I'm still trying but It wont work for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Php attachment from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129848/php-attachment-from-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As always, make sure you're using a recent version of PHPMailer.

You need to use `addStringAttachment`, docs [here](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer-PHPMailer-PHPMailer.html#method_addStringAttachment):

```
$photo_thumbnail_url = 'http://t2.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/76/44/75/400_F_76447580_gOWAV0P8APW0iC51OsW5huD6qoiEsh7O.jpg';
$mail->addStringAttachment(file_get_contents($photo_thumbnail_url), 'selected.jpg');
```

The `msgHTML` function handles `data` URLs automatically, converting them to embedded images with automatic `cid` values, so if your image is already embedded in your HTML, you don't have to do anything for it to work.

If you want to handle data URL conversion yourself, you can see how it works [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/c00fdf7b9aa7452650f852497cefe3152af553e7/class.phpmailer.php#L2903).

Answer (score 0):

Make SURE that your PHPMailer library is up-to-date!

and then try this one,

```
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage($photo_thumbnail_url, 'selected.jpg');
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage($croped_img, 'croped_img.jpg');
```

Comment: It's doesn't work. I would like to attach instead of embed. In documentation I found this: AddAttachment($path,$name,$encoding,$type); but It still won't work.